Is an EMF generated in conducting loop moving completely in a uniform magentic field?
According to Griffith's E&M textbook, Faraday's law in the case of a moving conductor in a uniform magnetic field is just a consequence of Lorentz force law. It gives the example of a loop moving out of a uniform magnetic field to support this claim. While I understand this example, I can't figure out how change in flux relates to the creation of EMF in a similar situation. He derives the work done from Lorenz force equation to show that the two approaches give the same result. However, when I try to apply the same logic for a loop moving in a space with a uniform magnetic field throughout it, Lorenz force tells me that the material should be polarised,i.e, an EMF is developed, while Faraday's law, and many sources claim that there is no change in flux, so no EMF is developed. What am I getting wrong?
